# Python 3.8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.5.3 error: ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'pango-1.0-0'

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I am trying to deploy an app on elastic beanstalk Python 3.8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.5.3 server. I have weasyprint and GTK3 installed in my pc. Also 'C:\Program Files\GTK3-Runtime Win64\bin' exists in system environment variables.

When I create an environment on elastic beanstalk using:

```
eb create django-env
```

I get an error:

```
OSError: cannot load library 'pango-1.0-0': pango-1.0-0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'pango-1.0-0'
```

WeasyPrint is running fine on my windows system. But after environment creation on aws elastic beanstalk, I get the error in logs. I already checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70031075/ctypes-util-find-library-did-not-manage-to-locate-a-library-called-pango-1-0), but its not of much help to windows users

Comment: Is this answer helpful ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50988421/13339621

Comment: I checked the link mentioned by you. Does that mean I won't be able to create the environment on elastic beanstalk without errors. I have no issues on windows machine

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood something in your post... Actually it seems elastic beanstalk is based on another linux distribution (probably centOS). It uses another package manager than apt-get: yum or dnf. So maybe you can try the command lines mentioned here: https://installati.one/centos/7/pango/ .

Comment: I'm a windows user and the environment creation is on linux system. What changes do I need to do in my windows machine so that on running 'eb create django-env' in terminal or command prompt I don't get the error  in elastic beanstalk?

Comment: Thanks for replying @matleg but the commands are not of much help to me

Comment: Can the solutions on link below be of any help? https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1690. I've added weasyprint.config but still getting the error. Any help will be appreciated